# Enhancing Biparental Heap and Rotated List

Tags: data-structures, heap

Heap is efficient when it comes to insert and delete but for search operation it requires O(n) comparisons. 
To improve on searching we modify heap and create biparental heap (beap) in which every node has two parents. Rest all aspects are same as heap.Searching in beap takes O(sqrt(2n)) comparisons.

Can someone explain me how can we further reduce the time spent on searching on arbitrary node by making some modifications to beap.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The "biparental heap" is described in this [Research Report](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/research/tr/1979/CS-79-31.pdf) from 1979.

That suggests two ways of improving on the O(sqrt(2n)) search time:

1. by sorting each level, and insisting that all nodes at level i are less than all nodes at level i+1... so that the search can be assisted by a binary chop, giving a respectable O(log(n)).  The insertion, not surprisingly becomes more complicated, and still O(sqrt(N)).
2. by increasing the branching factor, so that the work is O(cube-root(N))

[But, noting the wording of the question, you've already found the Research Report, so I fear I'm not telling you very much.]

I'm a big fan of the 'heap' structure, a very big fan... but I think it is wise to understand its limitations.  Your heap is a very fine way of running a priority queue.  Your heap sort is an excellent sort, with a guaranteed upper bound -- but not quite as good as quick sort, on average.  For anything else... there are better data structures.

An AVL tree will give you O(log(n)) search, insertion and deletion.  Which is heaps better (pun intended) than O(sqrt(2n)).  The more complicated biparental heap will do your O(log(n)) search, but insert and delete are still O(sqrt(n)).  If you want a structure which requires no node pointers (like the heap) I'm sure one could create an AVL tree that way.

For n=1000000 (a million), O(log2(n)) is ~20 while O(sqrt(2n)) is ~1414... its hard to get excited about the biparental heap :-(

Seems to me that this is an interesting idea, whose time never came.  (Or, as AA Milne put it in [The Engineer](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=tZkBAQAAQBAJ&pg=PT50&lpg=PT50&dq=let%20it%20rain%20who%20cares%20ive%20a%20train%20upstairs&source=bl&ots=23jnDkQgFl&sig=JbP6CqOXqBt-bQnss6P7c9xZtyE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=GggfVPzBM8GM7Ab9zoD4Cg&ved=0CFsQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q&f=false) -- we have here "a good sort of brake...".)

Comment: When you use AVL tree, you effectively steal users' memory from them for maintaining the boring pointers. Not big a crime as everyone does that for decades, and now gigabytes of memory are being stolen and computers are slower than ever (they swap, dude!), but still little to be proud of.

Comment: "If you want a structure which requires no node pointers (like the heap) I'm sure one could create an AVL tree that way." - you can create, you can't maintain. While beap does. "For n=1000000 (a million), O(log2(n)) is ~20 while O(sqrt(2n)) is ~1414". - And O(n) is 1000000 (e.g. 500000 elements move on average to insert into a sorted array), so you'd better get excited about beap again.